# How can just new born baby can walk ?

Tags: human-biology

This website [here](http://www.indiatimes.com/culture/who-we-are/this-video-of-baby-walking-immediately-after-being-born-is-breaking-the-internet-322619.html) stating video of New born baby walking breaking the internet.

How can just new born baby can walk ?

Comment: Just a stepping reflex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_reflexes#Walking.2Fstepping_reflex . That's it, too much internet for today, i'm gonna read a book... (PS: I speak portuguese, and that midwife seems very surprised. I believe she is faking or exagerating, because she should know that this is a normal reflex).

Comment: The baby isn't walking exactly. It can't support it's own weight. It's stepping: moving its feet in a step-like fashion when the tops of the feet are brushed against a surface or placed on the surface, a primitive reflex like the Moro Reflex, present in all normal newborns.

Comment: @anongoodnurse are you saying website is wrong?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - I've tested every newborn I've delivered or taken care of, and I have to admit this one is impressive, if only because 1) the baby is being held aloft so long and effortlessly by the...person, and 2) the baby usually gives up after a few 'steps', at least, *I* gave up then, as the point is not to see how long they can do it, but that it's there. So, all in all, it's a fun vid. Don't rag on the midwife. I would have commented as well, and I've seen it hundreds of times.

Comment: @DhanrajKumar - I didn't say anything about the video or the website. You see what you see. I'm explaining what is happening.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, it's impressive, but they (both of them, the midwife and the person who's filming, which I believe also work at the hospital) are talking like this was never seen before.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Well, then, I agree with you. It's for the camera, I guess.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Actually, to be fair, I just watched it again, the person surprised is the person filming, and maybe she is not aware of this reflex (or she's aware, but was excited). The only thing the midwife/nurse says is "she walked from here to there... I was about to give her a bath". So, the midwife is not that impressed.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - That makes sense. I don't understand Portuguese (wish I did), but it sounded to me like an excited grandma ("Oh, look at what my beautiful, talented, miraculous new grandchild can do!" kind of thing. Nice of the midwife to give grandma such a sweet treat for posterity. (Grinch that I was, I would have been more concerned with getting the baby dried off/warmed up.)

Comment: Yes, it's probably someone from the family, a grandma or an aunt! By the way, I'm seeing several websites translating the conversation, with expressions like "heavens above", "good lord" etc... they (the nurse and the grandma) are **not** saying that this is a miracle, those are common expressions in portuguese (spoken even by atheists)! Good on you, being worried about getting the baby dried off/warmed up... but since this is a preparation for a bath, it's probably several hours after the birth, or even a day later, isn't it?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Don't honestly know. Still has a lot of vernix (caseosa) on it. Lots of it wiped off. Could be a few hours, yes.

Comment: @DhanrajKumar- http://www.techtimes.com/articles/208562/20170529/watch-video-of-newborn-baby-who-tried-to-walk-immediately-after-birth.htm